# mvn&java doesn't work after macos upgrading (bigsur)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3, macos-big-sur

I installed java and maven in `Catalina` and everything works fine.

After upgrading to `bigsur`, mvn can not work.

> 错误: 加载主类 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher 时出现 LinkageError
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void java.util.zip.Inflater.initIDs()'

I have reinstalled `openjdk` and `maven` again. Not work.

I found it works fine with `sudo`. So I tried to give the directory authority by:

> sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/install 
> chmod 755 /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/install

Not work.

I have restarted my mbp. Not work.

Besides, when i tried run `java -jar xxx.jar`, i got following errors:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void java.util.zip.Inflater.initIDs()'
> at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.initIDs(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.(Inflater.java:116)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.getInflater(ZipFile.java:719)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.(ZipFile.java:416)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:383)
> at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:788)
> at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:420)
> at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:407)
> at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(LauncherHelper.java:542)
> at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:767)
> at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:675)

All my tricks have been exhausted. Please help.

> java -version
> openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20 OpenJDK Runtime
> Environment (build 15.0.1+9) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9,
> mixed mode, sharing)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvLJt.png)

Comment: Did you install multiple versions of java? Have you tried reinstalling Java?

Comment: no, just one.I tried, but it doesn't work@dan1st

Comment: @markwave hey I'm having a similar issue- did u ever figure this out?